# Android onBackPressed - force parent onCreate

Tags: android, android-activity

I have `FirstActivity` that calls:

```
Intent in = new Intent(this, SecondActivity.class);
startActivity(in);
```

After that, I perform some actions in SecondActivity and I go back using `onBackPressed()` or `finish()`.

The problem is, both thoose methods are moving me to `FirstActivity` without recreating it. On the other hand, if I press built-in menu button that moves me back in hierarchy, `FirstActivity` is recreated (so calls `onCreate()`) which is desired effect in my case.

The question is, what code should I call in `SecondActivity` in order to close this activity aswell as recreating `FirstActivity` (so it calls `onCreate()`)

Comment: Why do you want to recreate the FirstActivity? Is there any specific need? Otherwise you could also override some other lifecylce-methods, like onStart or onResume to perform your necessary initializations when returning from SecondActivity.

Comment: Once FirstActivity is initialized in onCreate it remains static. SecondActivity performs major changes in data displayed by FirstActivity, so I want to rebuild FirstActivity with minimum amount of code (I don't care efficiency)

Comment: "If I press built-in menu button that moves me back in hierarchy, FirstActivity is recreated" this should only be the case if it was destroyed during your time in `SecondActivity`. Seems like a flaw in your design.

Comment: I've been asking about code, not design. This is what stackoverflow is about, isn't it ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, you should think of whether you really want `onCreate()` to be called. You could move `FirstActivity`'s code that needs to be called to `onResume()` instead of `onCreate()`. That might be the easiest solution to your problem.

If you really want to call the `onCreate()` again in `FirstActivity` you could take a look at the flags you can give to your intent.

[Here is a list of available flags](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#setFlags(int)) Then start the first activity again with `startActivity()`.

Comment: Your list of flags is way too obtuse...I hate when people just give links instead of explaining something.

Comment: Seems like the url changed. I edited it to point to the list directly. I believe google's explanation is better than what I can offer. Feel free to vote down if you think my answer is not useful.

Answer (score 1):

In first Activity

```
Intent in = new Intent(this, SecondActivity.class);
startActivity(in);
finish();
```

Here you are destroying the current Activity.

From second activity

```
Intent in = new Intent(this, FirstActivity.class);
startActivity(in);
finish();
```

Whenever go back to the first Activity just destroy the second and recreate

Edit
Override `onkeydownmethod()`

```
 @Override
    public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event)  {
        if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK && event.getRepeatCount() == 0) {
            // do something on back.
//here you use intent
            return true;
        }

        return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
    }
```

Comment: This one is close, but once I finish FirstActivity I can't back to it from SecondActivity's built-in menu back button.

Comment: You can override onkeyDown().

Answer (score 1):

You can use `startActivityForResult()`, and when you return from second activity handle it in `onActivityResultcode()` do what you need. But I agree with others answers, that you should use some of Activity lifecycle methods.

```
public static fina int RESULT_CODE = 5;
Intent intent = new Intent(this, SecondActivity.class);
startActivityForResult(intent, 0);

....


 @Override
 protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
     if(resultCode == RESULT_CODE ){
      //do what you need
     }
 }
```

in SecondActivity simply set result code

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    setResult(FirstActivity.RESULT_CODE);
    this.finish();
}
```

Comment: I've seen this solution, but there is too much code. onResume() is perfect for me.